# Is it possible to create samples, that are not contained inside the data set?

Tags: machine-learning

I want to try machine learning and I am using a wine dataset from kaggle. I want to try predicting the points that wines will get. However, only point ratings from 80 to 100 are included in this data set. Is there some method, by which I could generate new samples with accurate point ratings from 0 to 80 or should I just take another data set?

Comment: If you just want to try how well prediction works outside the value range of the data, you could take the data with ratings 90-100 only (or whatever subrange of 80-100) and then test with the data outside that range.

Comment: There are lots of ways to "generate" such samples, however the generated samples are obviously not real (and the given answer by HowdyEarth explains why they will not normally be "as good as real"), and therefore they won't serve to check results against real data, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, creating new data points is paradoxically incorrect. In order to accurately generate data points with values from 0-80, you would need to have an accurate model to generate said data points. But you can't generate an accurate model without having the data points...

There are two options open to you, depending on how you frame your problem:

1) As a regression problem, you should limit the predictions your model makes. While some limited extrapolation may be allowable (Predictions from 70-100), you declare that your model is unable to predict anything below that. Extrapolation should be based off of model complexity. The advantage with this is that an exact score is predicted rather than a range. The disadvantage is that there isn't much of a level of confidence you can give outside of using standard deviations.

2) As a classification problem (E.g., create 20 buckets, 1 for every 5 points), then you can get a score reflecting the model's confidence of its prediction. The advantage of this is that your model will tell you how likely it believes a prediction to be true, but the disadvantage is that it will provide a range of values rather than an exact prediction.

Either way, predicting data outside the ranges of your training data is generally a bad idea unless you:

- Are super confident in your model's ability to extrapolate, which should only be the case when you have a model with a high predictive power and a low number of model parameters.
- Have some underlying, well-founded domain knowledge of the problem.

I certainly wouldn't try to generate data.